# how to replace the first column of a tab delimited file

Tags: vim

```
690070  690070  A
690451  690451  B
690571  690571  C
690578  690578  D
690637  690637  F
```

How can I replace the first column values with a sequential number, starting from 1...n. So it becomes:

```
1  690070  A
2  690451  B
3  690571  C
4  690578  D
5  690637  F
```

Can this be done in Vim or some linux command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Vim:

```
:let i=1 | g/^[^/\t]*\t/s//\= i. "\t"/ | let i=i+1
```

[Reference](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Making_a_list_of_numbers)

**Update**

For splitting the first two columns and saving into another file,

I recommend using `awk` as in Tomáš Šíma's answer, specifically:
`awk '{print $1 "\t" $2;}'  data.stat > newfilename.txt`

If you want to to do everything in Vim:

- Copy the current file to a new one

`:w newfilename.txt`

- Open the newly copied file:

`:o newfilename.txt`

- Split the first two columns of the rest of the line:

`:%s/^\([^\t]*\)\t\([^\t]*\).*$/\1\t\2/g`

- Save your edits of course

`:w newfilename.txt`

Comment: Perfect, if I want to split the first two columns into another file, how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use awk or vim macro.
**awk** is really great for such text manipulation

```
awk '{count++; print count " " $2 " "$3;}'  data.stat > /tmp/data.stat && mv /tmp/data.stat data.stat
```

Comment: Probably easier to use `NR` instead of count. e.g. `awk '{print NR, $2, $3}'`